# ANN becomes jumpy after some iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

The code is a simplified replication of a problem that I encountered. For this very simple task, the loss reduced quickly (after 2000+ episodes) to e-10 level. However, after that, loss suddenly begin to increase, to around e-02 to e-04 level, stay there for a short while and then reduce to e-10 again and then again and again.

My first guess is this is due to that a too high learning rate (I have a learning rate decay though), but then I feel it's not quite right. The loss function in our case is perfectly convex and symmetric, so if it's due to high learning rate, it should be staying around a certain level, but not increase and then decrease.

The code attached can also reproduce similar results. I've also attached below a graph from tensorboard, the small pulses are very common and can be reproduced in most cases, but the large jump might not be reproduced as I only see it once or twice in my own running. The graph is not quite clear, but based on the printed results, the loss will stay at a high level for tens of episodes, not just one.

Is there any mathematical reason behind this? Thank you.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

def generate_data(batch_size,size):
    x_val=np.random.rand(batch_size,size)
    y_val=np.mean(x_val,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    return x_val,y_val

#-------------------------------------------Initialize-----------------------------------------------------
tf.reset_default_graph()
gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.15)
sess=tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

batch_size=8192
size=100

inputs=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,size])
label=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1])

loss_summary = tf.Variable(0.)
summary_ops=tf.summary.scalar("Loss", loss_summary)
writer= tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir="tensorboard", graph=sess.graph)
#-------------------------------------------Model-----------------------------------------------------
net=tf.layers.dense(inputs,100)
net=tf.layers.dense(net,1)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(net-label))
global_step=tf.get_variable(name='global_step',shape=(),trainable=False,dtype=tf.int16,initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
lr= tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=0.001,global_step=global_step,
                                                        decay_steps=500,decay_rate=0.99,name="lr")
opt=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)

#-----------------------------------------Run-------------------------------------------------------
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10000):
    t=time.time()
    x_val,y_val=generate_data(batch_size=batch_size,size=size)
    loss_val,_=sess.run([loss,opt],{inputs:x_val,label:y_val})
    summary=sess.run(summary_ops,feed_dict={loss_summary:loss_val})
    writer.add_summary(summary,i)
    writer.flush()
    print('Episode {}, loss {}, time {}'.format(i,loss_val,time.time()-t))
```

Comment: Although I haven't tried out your code, the incredibly high batch size got my attention. You could try running with a lower batch size instead - most researchers suggest sizes below 512, unless you _really_ have to use such a large batch size, for whatever reason. This could also potentially stabilize training, since you are doing more frequent updates; generally, since you are creating this with a random generator, it could also be some form of interal pattern of the random number generator.